# Library to parse HTTP Responses with Arduino

Tags: arduino, httpresponse

I'm looking for a library to parse a web HTTP response with Arduino separating, for example, the HTTP Headers from the content.

Reading the various sketches out there, the most advanced tool to parse a stream of data is [TextFinder](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/TextFinder).

Are you aware of any other libraries that could help in parsing an HTTP Response?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Someone's been working on an Arduino library for HTTP Client applications:

https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient

Comment: I am having issues with this Library with a Google App Engine backend. It seems the lib does not support chunked encoding and so strange characters show up when I read my response. It might be as easy as telling the lib to use HTTP 1.0 if supported by app engine.

Comment: Documentation here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101 (Search for "Client class", you can find it in the sidebar on the right)

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is to get rid of the headers, then this bit of code works fine for me:

```
char c = client.read();
result = result + c;    

**// Delete HTTP headers
if(result.endsWith("Content-Type: text/plain"))
{
  result="";
}**
```

I store my response in a String object, and empty it when the last header arrives.
I am not an HTTP expert, not sure if this header is always the last to arrive :)

You might also have some spaces, new lines etc. left, simply "trim" the String before printing it!

Comment: Constructing a `String` by adding a single character a time is a surefire way to get your heap fragmented.

Comment: @pfabri Can you expand on that comment? Or at least provide a link to some explanation. (I see a lot of heap problems!)

Comment: [This](https://cpp4arduino.com/2018/11/06/what-is-heap-fragmentation.html) and [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=366035.0) will explain...

Answer (score 4):

There are two main alternatives:

1. https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient
2. https://github.com/interactive-matter/HTTPClient

The main differences I have seen so far:

- #1 has zero documentation, #2 has quite decent documentation
- #1 requires you to construct your URLs manually; #2 lets you supply e.g. an array of parameter name=value pairs
- #2 requires you to provide the Arduino's IP address and the target URL's IP address, #1 uses Arduino 1.0's built-in DHCP and DNS lookup libraries

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple Arduino shields and libraries out there for using the Arduino as a web server and could be a good place to start.

The [TinyWebServer](http://www.webweavertech.com/ovidiu/weblog/archives/000484.html) has a downloadable HTTP library that may handle header parsing too.

Some web server code from the Arduino Playground (may only handle HTTP requests):

- http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/WebServer
- http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer

Answer (score 1):

A fork from the amcewen/HttpClient that is well documented with a number of good examples

[Arduino Librariries ArduinoHttpClient](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient)